# What statistical method to use to analyse decrease in energy usage if production is always increasing?

Tags: time-series, correlation, multiple-regression, descriptive-statistics

**Production** at a factory is always increasing (tonelage), and **energy** (MWh) consumption is directly proportional, which would be a positive correlation. In parallel, there is investment and effort for increasing energy efficiency and decrease its usage:

*How can I study how much actual energy is being saved from those efforts alone, if the energy increase because of production will always be more than what can actually be saved?*

If production was stable, I could just see an overall decrease trend in energy and correlate that to the energy saving methods, but production is forecasted to keep increasing, and machinery and equipment still hasn´t reached its full capacity, so no way to know a baseline of energy consumption behaviour.

*Is there a statistical method which would allow me to know an approximate of a certain decrease in consumption correlated to a specific efficiency improvement vs the normal increase trend of energy and Production?*

Also, what would be the correct description of this phenomenon or situation?

Update:
[image]

Comment: I don't understand. What is wrong with energy costs divided by turnover?

Comment: In the end I´m trying to measure how much energy (as little as it may be) I´m saving. My energy performance is measured MWh/Ton of product produced. I´m not looking into finantial costs. For example, lets say a certain month my MWH/Ton = 1.0, the next month production was up and thus the efficiency increased so now MWh/Ton = 0.8; I produced a bit more and my energy consumption also increased but only a bit, but also I replaced a certain equipment to a more energy efficient one, but I´m not sure how much the influnce of changing that equipment actually was...

Comment: Would you have expected the energy performance to stay constant without the replacement of equipment?

Comment: No, it would still be getting more efficient, but because of the increase of production itself, not because of the small influnce of changing the equipment. Does the image I just added help?